# Executing CGI under apache without a shebang? Or how to execute CGI in a server neutral manner

Tags: apache, web, cgi, legacy

So I find myself in a strange situation whereby I need to understand old skool CGI (simple CGI) execution under Apache web server. Yes, I know, in a real setup we use an Apache module or FastCGI! But anyway...

As I understand it, an Apache CGI script looks like this (perl in this example, but could be anything):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "Hello, World.";
```

This was borrowed from here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html

You would then use the following apache directives to make sure that perl scripts were executed as CGI:

```
<Directory ...>
    ...
    Options +ExecCGI                                             
    AddHandler cgi-script .pl
</Directory>
```

That's great it works. Note how Apache relies upon the shebang to decide the interpreter to run the script as.

Under lighttpd though, this works differently. In the server config we state explicitly which interpreter to use on a per file extension basis, e.g.:

```
cgi.assign = (                                                                  
        ".php" => "/usr/local/bin/php",                          
        ".pl" => "/usr/bin/perl"                                                
)
```

If lighttpd comes to execute a script with a shebang, it seems it is ignored. Fine.

My question is, is there a way to do something like this in Apache? Can I specify which interpreter to use in the server configuration so that scripts do not need a shebang. Presumably people did not (back when CGI was the in thing) go adding shebangs to each and every PHP file so that the app could be run in Apache/CGI.

I have been unable to find an answer in the Apache docs. So maybe you can't do this?

EDIT: Also, whose responsibility is it to send the `Content-Type` header. Did people really manually output that back in the CGI days? I don't recall ever seeing a PHP script that did this.

Cheers